# JSON-LD Missing '}' or object member name. error

Tags: json, json-ld

I like to add json-ld to my website before that I want to add it to my dev site to test it

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "contactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+xx-xxx-xxx-xxxx",
    "contactType": "customer service"

  }]
}
</script>
```

I get the error stating that Missing '}' or object member name. what is this error,I have closed brackets correctly.how to fix it kindly help

Comment: It may be valid JSON, but it's not valid javascript.

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This snippet is completely fine. It is both valid JSON as well as valid JSON-LD. You can test it with the [JSON-LD playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/) and [Google's Structured Data Testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool).

Answer (score 51):

Usually this error is because of **unneeded commas**, make sure to remove the trailing comma from all last elements in every { } block.

Example snippet:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Article",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "http://foo.bar", // Remove comma here
    }, // Remove comma here

    // Add other required fields if necessary
}
</script>
```

Comment: Also This should be the accepted answer as per Question asked

Comment: Original question didn't have trailing commas.

Comment: Google Search Console gives this error - "Parsing error: Missing '}' or object member name" - for pages with an unnecessary comma.

Comment: 2020 and this anomaly still exists. Do not forget double quotes to all "key":"values" as well. Is google bots connected to their AI department ??

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the exact same issue. The JSON-LD markup has nothing to do with trailing commas after the last element, etc. Yours is absolutely correct.

However, please note that single quotes or `''` are not accepted by Google. You must use double quotes or `""` for each and every key and value, including the elements in an array and not the array itself.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue and found a unusual reason for the error. In my case an unknown blank character was causing the issue.

I simply replaced all those unknown blank characters with spaces and it worked for me.

Se attached images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your schema have this

> &quot;

then try to replace it with normal

> "

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was simply a case of removing trailing spaces that were after a comma.

Specifically `"ratingValue": "4.9",`   became `"ratingValue": "4.9",`in this block:

```
"aggregateRating":
    {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.9",  
        "bestRating": "5",
        "reviewCount": "91"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened to me. In my case, it works just deleting the last coma after "" and putting and the end after `}`.

```
"contactType": "customer service"     <== 
(YOU DONT HAVE COMMA HERE, BUT IF THIS IS THE CASE YOU SHOULD DELETE THE COMA)

   }],     <==(AND PUT IT HERE)
},     <==(OR HERE, YOU JUST TRY IT)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Rich Result Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) tool also shows this error for large JsonLD inputs.

I wonder if this is just a limitation of the test tool or google crawlers also follow this rule.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem, but this is not just all about extra commas and spacing.

just change this:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "contactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+xx-xxx-xxx-xxxx",
    "contactType": "customer service"

  }]
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "contactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+xx-xxx-xxx-xxxx",
    "contactType": "customer service"

  }]
}
```

The problem simply occurs because yours is "http://schema.org", and it must be changed to "https://schema.org"