# Missing '}' or object member name in JSON-LD

Tags: javascript, schema, json-ld, json-schema-validator

I have already tried solutions that were mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053609/json-ld-missing-or-object-member-name-error#:%7E:text=Usually%20this%20error%20is%20because,elements%20in%20every%20%7B%20%7D%20block.&text=Original%20question%20didn%27t%20have%20trailing%20commas.&text=Google%20Search%20Console%20gives%20this,pages%20with%20an%20unnecessary%20comma.)

I've already countless checked for trailing commas, white spaces, uneven curly bracket. But none of them worked. Can someone help what is wrong with my schema?

Check this link using the validator.schema website [here](https://validator.schema.org/?hl=en-GB#url=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelop--radiant-malasada-b64d2c.netlify.app%2Fp%2Ffoothill-blvd-santa-ana-ca-92705-52061555%2F)

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "RealEstateListing",
    "name": "8 Bedroom Residential",
    "description": "Romantic and impressive Mediterranean estate situated on a one acre, street to street view lot in the hills of coveted North Tustin, Villa Fiorile is a custom gated estate in an unmatched setting with mature trees and lush gardens. Grand, intimate, and rich in character and style, this residence is accented by saturated colors, arched windows and doors, interior arched casings, and exposed wood-beamed ceilings. Upon entering the residence, one is welcomed by a dramatic entry hall that leads into the majestic living room anchored by a fireplace with European mahogany windows offering expansive views from Catalina to Palos Verdes and beyond.  French doors in the adjacent sun room lead out to serene grounds with a sparkling all-tile swimming pool. The spacious property offers a main house with five bedrooms, three of which are large enough to be primary suites, each adorned with luxurious spa-like Carrara marble baths. The two additional bedrooms have their own baths. Rich mahogany patio doors and windows surround the home and encourage indoor and outdoor living. Materials used throughout are rarely seen in today’s homes. From the expansive formal living and dining rooms, cozy family room with fireplace and sitting room, and charming kitchen, the authentic Mediterranean finishes showcase the home’s timeless style. The grounds feature an expansive lawn, patios with old world fountains, garden, majestic oak and palm trees, a two-story guest house and separate casita. Homes of this",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "1621 FOOTHILL BLVD",
      "addressLocality": "SANTA ANA",
      "addressRegion": "CA",
      "postalCode": "92705",
      "addressCountry": "US"
    },
    "geo": {
      "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
      "latitude": 33.760629,
      "longitude": -117.785239
    },
    "image": "https://api1.realtytrac.com/api/v1/properties/photo?u=AZbWrYHm2bcgjXps4ixc7OKvon-poleUd_Rd7GqF0TYPpYtz3JiXjv6_K0Q-Heoc5MAqCPP_s-MxdpH0EIUTFcLOyjCt60liESSDdXwvI7wlsOHWdCkN2XO2BEW8x0mfG5SskhXp9OiFDyghsxT5XM3S-n8o",
    "offers": {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "priceCurrency": "USD",
      "price": "$4999000",
      "URL": "https://www.realtytrac.com/p/foothill-blvd-santa-ana-ca-92705-52061555/",
      "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock"
    },
    "url": "https://www.realtytrac.com/p/foothill-blvd-santa-ana-ca-92705-52061555/"
  }
```

Tried validating it with validator.schema.org website and says Missing '}' or object member name.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source HTML of your website. It shows there is a `<script type="application/ld+json">` tag, who is just following the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex/nofollow"/>`, with the double encoded LD+JSON content. The content looks like this:

```
 &quot;@context&quot;: &quot;https://schema.org&quot;,
    &quot;@type&quot;: &quot;RealEstateListing&quot;,
```

Please check the [screenshot of your website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB974.png).

Comment: Yes, for some reason my website was giving duplicate ld+json script. One with the &quot; JSON text and the other one with the normal double quote " JSON.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix the problem. To those who may encounter the same thing in future. Here's what I did. For some context, I'm using nextJS and that script was placed on a particular page which was to be injected later on causing the duplication. To solve the double script problem, I had to use the built-in next/script instead and move it outside the next next/Head component (see screenshot below). Now, the schema validator only detected one ld+json script this time with the valid JSON value.

[image]